# Type X is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Y'

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, object, intrinsicattributes

The type of the array of objects looks as follows: `MyType: { name: string, age: number }[]`, props type in component is the same

```
./Parent.jsx
export const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <Content data={arrOfObj} />
  )
}

./Content.jsx

export const Content: React.FC<MyType> = (data) => {...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you wanted

```
<Content data={arrOfObj} /> // warning

const Content: React.FC<{ data: MyType }> = ({ data }) => {...}
```